# Is there a way to get notified when the build output changes in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I'm doing some batch work using Jenkins.

And I want to be notified when the output of the stand output is different from the previous build.

For example,
If I run the following bash shell on jenkins, the output of the previous build will be different if the build date is changed.

```
# /bin/bash
date "+DATE: %Y-%m-%d"
```

## build - #1

DATE: 2018-06-05

## build - #2

DATE: 2018-06-05

## build - #3

DATE: 2018-06-06

Can I get notifications like email, slack, etc. only when the execution result is different from the previous one, as in the above build 3?
Could you let me know if you have a plug-in that makes this possible or if Jenkins already supports it?

I am very grateful for your help. 
:)

Comment: If you are storing artifacts, can't you compare the current with the previous one and send notification only when it has changed?

Comment: yeah, I would like to receive a notification email only if the build output is different from the result of the previous build.

And I could save the output as a file and add logic to the shell script to compare with the previous build, but I would like to handle this in jenkins itself.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if there is a plugin but in pipeline it's possible. Get current build log with: `currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(number_of_lines)` and then compare it with the previous build log: `Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName('build_name').getBuildByNumber(env.BUILD_NUMBER.toInteger() - 1).logFile.text`

If they are not equal send email: `emailext body: 'build produced a different output than previous', subject: 'notification', to: 'me@mail.com'`

Comment: thank you for helping me! I'm not used to using jenkins yet, so I think I need to research on setting up a pipeline job. Thank you again for giving me the detailed code and instructions.

Comment: @ponvolax, welcome to stackoverflow. If the answer provided a solution or helped you find one, please accept/upvote the answer.

Comment: @SilentMonk, Thanks! I will do that.

Comment: Oh, I cannot do upvote now because I do not have enough reputation.